# ${\lim_{x\to 0^+}}\frac{(\sin ( 3x))^{10}(\ln ( 4x+1))^{20}(1-\cos ( 6x))^{15}}{(\sin ( x))^{19}(\ln ( 8x+1 ))^{41}}$

Tags: calculus, limits

$${\lim_{x\to 0^+}}\frac{(\sin(3x))^{10}\left(\ln(4x+1 )\right)^{20}(1-\cos (6x))^{15}}{(\sin x)^{19}\left(\ln ( 8x+1 )\right)^{41}}$$

I arrived to $$\frac{3^{10}*4^{20}*3^{30}*2^{15}}{8^{60}}$$

using \begin{align}
&\lim _{x\to 0}\frac{ \sin x}{x}=1 \\
&\lim _{x\to 0}\frac{\ln(x+1)}{x}=1 \\
&\lim _{x\to 0}\frac{1-\cos x}{x^2}=\frac{1}{2}\end{align}

But it is incorrect

Comment: The $8^{60}$ should be $8^{41}$.

Comment: Why don't you use:$$\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{1-\cos x}{x^2}=\frac{1}{2}?$$

Comment: $$\lim_{x\to 0}\left(\frac{1-\cos(6x)}{36x^2}\right)^{15}\cdot 6^{30}\cdot x^{30}$$ It is $2^{30}\cdot 3^{30}$

Answer (score 1):

$${\lim_{x\to 0^+}}(\frac{\sin(3x)}{3x})^{10}(\frac{\ln(4x+1)}{4x})^{20}(\frac{\sin^2(6x)}{(6x)^2})^{15}(\frac{x}{\sin(x)})^{19}(\frac{8x}{\ln(8x+1)})^{41}\frac{(3x)^{10}(4x)^{20}(6x)^{30}}{2^{15}x^{19}(8x)^{41}}=\frac{3^{10}\cdot4^{20}\cdot6^{30}}{2^{15}\cdot8^{41}}=0.0411917728221$$